# CountIf over multiple ranges?

Tags: excel

I have the following CountIf formula to count how many times the word "yes" appears in a range.

```
=COUNTIF((H2:H9,H14:H23,H30,H62:H90), "Yes")
```

However, this is giving me a `#VALUE` error, though I can't see what's wrong with it. Adjusting it to

```
=COUNTIF(H62:H90, "Yes")
```

removes the problem. So is there a problem with how I'm representing the multiple ranges?

Thanks,

Comment: How you considered summing the `CountIfs` for the different ranges?

Comment: I have not. Will try now. So I can't use one CountIf over a non-continuous range?

Comment: No, the range must be continuous in COUNTIF()

Comment: Thanks. 

      `=SUM(COUNTIF(H2:H9, "Yes"),COUNTIF(H14:H23, "Yes"), COUNTIF(H30, "Yes"), COUNTIF(H62:H90, "Yes"))`

This works. Cheers!

Comment: There are some workarounds, e.g. this version only uses a single COUNTIF.....but you need some other functions to make it work...`=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"H2:H9","H14:H23","H30","H62:H90"}), "Yes"))`